# Add new datafields/groups after database expert wizard finishes?

Tags: sql, t-sql, crystal-reports

It seems I cant add new data fields or groups to Crystal Reports after the database wizard completes. I know i can drag new data fields into the grid, but it lacks any specific grouping/filtering/linked ID's.

For example:

When you create a report you can choose filters and linked ID's via a wizard. AFTER I complete the wizard, if I add a completely new table, the data will not be correct (even if there are common ids to match.) Other then using selection formula to solve this issue, you would think there is an easy way to modify the data from the wizard again. But not as far as I can tell.

Comment: This is not clear. Please clarify... what do you mean, "it lacks any specific grouping/filtering/linked IDs"? Grouping and filtering is handled at the report level and doesn't have much to do with dragging database fields onto the report.

Comment: When you create a report you can choose filters and linked ID's via a wizard. If I add a completely new table AFTER I complete the wizard the data will not be correct. Other then creating new grouping and creating a selection formula, you would think there is an easy way to modify the data from the wizard again. But not as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your grouping(s) by going to 'Report' -> 'Group Expert'. You can add a new table by going to 'Database' -> 'Database Expert' -> Selecting the table to add from the sources on the left. Then, define a join/link for that new table by hitting the 'Links' tab at the very top of that same dialogue box.

You don't need to use the wizard for any part of the report creation process. If that doesn't answer your question, please add more specifics about exactly what you're trying to do and the process you're following.